# Not able to handle runtime error 9 with on error go to [label]

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I have the followin code. But the error does not get handled

```
Sub Some_sub()

Some code here

On Error GoTo resumeCode
If Workbooks("Some file.xlsm").ReadOnly Then
    GoTo readOnlyError
End If

resumeCode:

On Error GoTo fileNotOpen
Workbooks("Some file.xlsm").Activate

some more code here

Exit Sub

fileNotOpen:
    MsgBox "Error: Claims followup.xlsm is not open." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & 
"Open the file in read/write"
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

When I run debug mode it shows me this line: `Workbooks("Some file.xlsm").Activate` in yellow. Instead of handling the error and going to the label.

Within VBA under Tools -> Options -> General Tab: Break on Unhandled Errors active.

When I have the file open it runs the code like it should. When it is closed it does not handle the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you have the file "some file.xlsm" opened while executing this code?
Do you have the line with fileNotOpen label defined in the same Sub?
Also: The showing the erroring line in Yellow is exactly what that Option you're referring to does. 
If you turn that option off, you should go to the "fileNotOpen" label **after** the yellow line fails (once more hitting F8).

Comment: @RikSportel the option `Break on Unhandled Errors` is actually the one that makes code jump to the error handling label without breaking. Anyway, @OP, in addition to the questions above, do you have some other `On Error` statements in the same sub?

Comment: I updated the code a bit. I have other on error go to labels yes, but they are before this error handling (attempt), and they work.

Comment: @A.S.H Yeah you're right, my bad. It'll break when unhandled (which it shouldn't be) yet bahves like it's unhandled (hence my questions).

Comment: @SergeInácio, if you had `On Error Resume Next` before that line and an error does occur, your new  `On Error GoTo fileNotOpen` wont work unless you call `Resume something`. Post some of those statements.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. When I call Resume the file freezes :S. I added some more code. hopefully now it is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it. As I said in the comments, when an error occurs, and you handle it, you cannot setup a new `On Error` mechanism until you explicitly invoke the `Resume` keyword in any way.

One possible way to achieve it, if you dont want to change the flow of your routine, is just to add a label before your new `On Error` statement and `Resume` on it. Like this, for example:

```
Sub Some_sub()
  ' Some code ...

  On Error GoTo resumeCode
  If Workbooks("Some file.xlsm").ReadOnly Then
    GoTo readOnlyError
  End If

  ' Some more code ...

resumeCode:
  Resume ResumeHere ' <---------------------------------------- Invoke Resume

ResumeHere:               ' <------------------------------------- Add some label

On Error GoTo fileNotOpen
Workbooks("Some file.xlsm").Activate

Exit Sub

fileNotOpen:
   msgBox "Error: Claims followup.xlsm is not open." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Open the file in read/write"
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

You should be careful though, the keyword `Resume` will itself raise an error if the error status is blank and it is reached from normal flow, In that case you should put the error handling sections, each apart, in the end of your routine and resume at any labels within the normal flow from there. This is generally the usual approach.

Comment: Wow. awesome, thank you so much for taking the time :)